# Rails model how to reference column in a class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I currently have 2 models - Issue and Responses and i'm trying to add a method on the response model so I can do `issue.responses.latest`

I'm currently getting `undefined method 'issue_id' for #<Class:...`

How can I reference the column `issue_id` from the responses table in my self.latest method?

```
class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :responses
end

class Response < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :issue

  def self.latest
    select([:id, :user_id, :issue_id, :response, 'MAX(created_at)'])
       .where(:issue_id => self.issue_id) <!-- How to reference the issue_id column here?
       .group(:issue_id)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're referencing the `issue_id` column fine. The problem is that you're trying to provide a *value* of `self.issue_id`, but there is no `issue_id` class method of `Response`.

Also, a `latest` class method for `Response` won't be invoked by `issue.responses.latest`, since `responses` is an `<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_Collec‌​tionProxy_Table:0x007f85220bd3b8>`. You could, however, define an `Issue` instance method of `latest_response`.

On a related point, since `responses` is an `Enumerable`, you can do `issues.responses.max_by {|response| response.created_at}`

Comment: If i remove the `self` on `self.issue_id` I get the error `undefined local variable or method 'issue_id'`

Comment: Right. What are you trying to filter on? That is, what value of `issue_id` are you intending to specify there?

Comment: I'm ultimately trying to do `issue.responses.latest` in my view to get the very last response to a particular issue.

Comment: Ok, well to begin with `issue.responses` is going to of be of type `#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Table:0x007f85220bd3b8>`. If you use `to_a` on the end of that, you'll get an array. Defining a class method for `Response` is not going to help you.

Comment: That is, not going to allow you to execute `issue.responses.latest`.

Comment: You could define an `Issue` instance method that would let you do `issue.latest_response` or you could define a `Response` class method that would let you do `Response.latest(issue.responses)`.

Comment: The only way you could have a method that would let you do `issue.responses.latest` is if you added an instance method to that `ActiveRecord` class I showed above, which doesn't seem like a good idea.